# Uploads speed is slow when HTTP/2 is used in AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an application (backed, frontend) deployed on an EKS cluster on AWS. The problem is that upload speed when HTTP/2 is used is much slower than HTTP/1.1. I made my research and found [articles](https://blog.cloudflare.com/delivering-http-2-upload-speed-improvements/) like this pointing out that the problem is mostly due to web servers configuration (like NGINX). Is there a workaround for this in AWS ALB? knowing that the files being upload to the application are mostly large (+50MiB) files.